# Grails File Upload Problems

Tags: spring, grails, file-upload

I'm trying to emulate the file upload code from the grails website, and I'm running into some problems.  I'm using the same code as found [here](http://grails.org/Controllers+-+File+Uploads).  Here is my code:

```
    <g:form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myFile" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </g:form>
```

and

```
def upload = {
    def f = request.getFile('myFile')
    if(!f.empty) {
      flash.message = 'success'
    }    
    else {
       flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the following error at runtime:

```
Message: No signature of method: org.mortbay.jetty.Request.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: {"myFile"}
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.mortbay.jetty.Request.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: {"myFile"}
```

It appears to be related to some Spring configuration. Spring does not appear to be injecting `MultipartHttpServletRequest`, so my request doesn't have the appropriate method.  I just created this applications using `grails create-app`.  I have not modified the resources.groovy file.  I'm using grails 1.0.3.

Any help is much appreciated.  The grails website makes this look so easy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem solved!

I was using the example code for uploading files to Grails differently than the original author probably intended.  The problem is that when the *upload* method of the controller was called, it was sometimes for the original render of the Upload page.  The request in that method was was not of type MultipartHttpServletRequest.  When I did a POST with my file to upload, then Spring did the correct thing and changed my requestion to MultipartHttpServletRequest.  So, I needed to do a simple check in my *update* controller method before using my request like a MultipartHttpServletRequest.

```
if(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest)
{
  MultipartHttpServletRequest mpr = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;  
  CommonsMultipartFile f = (CommonsMultipartFile) mpr.getFile("myFile");
  if(!f.empty)
    flash.message = 'success'
  else
   flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
}   
else
  flash.message = 'request is not of type MultipartHttpServletRequest'
```

Comment: Oh, ya....  you never want to allow POST and GET from the same action closure, just for this kind of thing.

Comment: If someone is looking for how to test this here is a good link http://roshandawrani.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/grails-mock-testing-a-file-upload/ thanks to Roshan

Answer (score 5):

Now with the Grails 2.x use:

```
<g:uploadForm name="upload" action="upload" method="POST">
     <input type="file" name="file" />
</g:uploadForm>

def upload = {
    def file = request.getFile('file')
    assert file instanceof CommonsMultipartFile

    if(!file.empty){ //do something }
    else { //do something }
}
```

More clean, more simple.

Answer (score 4):

make sure you update the html (your gsp with the form to upload from) to have the **enctype** as they show:

```
<g:form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Hope that is helpful, seems too obvious but it's my first thought after seeing your error message.

Comment: I have that but it still doesn't work.  I've added my exact code to my original post above.

Comment: thanks, see your update... trying to dig in... is it wierd that the Request is Jetty specific and not just an HttpRequest...

Comment: Admittedly I'm new to Grails.  I assumed since I was running my app using Jetty, it was normal for the request to by of type Jetty.

Answer (score 2):

Someone [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRAILS/File+Upload) seems to be having the same troubles you had.  He says he "fixed" it:

> Solved. It was my mistake, I was going in action save before submitting the form, so I suppose there was no file.

Not sure how to take what he said, but maybe it'll help you.

Comment: saw that, but had no idea how to communicate it... another guy says he did a clean and cleared his cache and it worked... not sure about that... but it worked for him somehow

Comment: I'm not sure how I go to the action before submitting.  Is ths possible?  I've cleaned my applications (grails clean), but I don't know how to clear caches.