# update user image in directory in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have each user's image in my project directory like user1.jpeg, user2.jpeg and so on. But when I try to change a user image it is throughing a error. I am not understanding what to do. Here is the error as follows >>>

```
Cannot cast object 'org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@21740230' with class 'org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest' to class 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest'
```

And here is my update action >>>

```
def updateUser = {
    String message = ""
    MultipartHttpServletRequest mpr = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;
    CommonsMultipartFile f = (CommonsMultipartFile) mpr.getFile("userPhoto")//getFile("userPhoto");

    if(!f.empty) {
        def user = User.get(1)
        user.avatarType = f.getContentType()
        if(user.save()){
            def userId = user.id
            String username = user.username
            println(userId)
            String fileName = username + "." + f.getContentType().substring(6)
            new File( grailsApplication.config.images.location.toString() ).mkdirs()
            f.transferTo( new File( grailsApplication.config.images.location.toString() + File.separatorChar + fileName) )
            message = "Here is your updated Information >>>  "
            render(view: 'userInfo', model: [message: message],)

        }else{
            message = "Can not Update User !!!"
            render(view: 'editUser', model:[message: message])
            return;
        }
    }else {
        flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this please? I am using grails 2.1.0.

**EDIT ::**

and here is the view for edit user >>>

```
<div class="main">
   <g:form controller="user" action="updateUser">
       User Name : ${username} <br/>
       Photo : <input type="file" name="userPhoto" /> <p></p>
       <g:hiddenField name="userId" id="userId" value="${userId}"/>
       <g:submitButton name="updateUser" value="Update" />
   </g:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // MultipartHttpServletRequest mpr = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;
 def f = request.getFile("userPhoto")//getFile("userPhoto");
```

I have to use `<g:uploadForm />` see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles

Comment: thanks for reply. But if I try your way it shows that "Cannot resolve symbol 'getFile" and this error is thrown >>> "No signature of method: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [userPhoto] Possible solutions: getXML(), getPart(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getInfo()"

Comment: still showing in controller >> "Cannot resolve symbol 'getFile' " and at runtime this error is thrown >> "Cannot get property 'empty' on null object"

Comment: which portion are you suggesting?

Comment: Controller code & GSP code from "Programmatic File Uploads" part GRAILS guides.

Comment: See the accepted answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206224/grails-file-upload-problems

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine in your code just add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag, like

```
<g:form controller="user" action="updateUser" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</g:form>
```

and your code works.